# Use alternate value if a field is null in Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I have field `A` and `B`. While indexing, if value of `A` is null, I want to get value of `B` instead.

```
Header: "header", id: "id", accessor:
 // if A is present in Elastic search, use A else use B.
```

I am thinking store this value to `C` so that I can use `C` later in query as well, but I am not sure about how to achieve it. I did not come across such a use case anywhere. Is it possible to handle this case ? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Nullish coalescing operator will help you, please take a look of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: could you please clarify your question with example of expected result for indexing in ES?